# Simple capacitor question

Tags: homework-and-exercises, capacitance

A parallel plate capacitor with air gap has capacitance 4 pF. A dielectric of dielectric constant 2 is pushed halfway into the gap as shown below.

[image]

The answer sheet claims that the new capacitance is 6 pF. However I believe it is 8 pF, because even if the area is half, the dielectric constant is 2, therefore from the capacitance equation (permittivity x area)/distance the total capacitance will be 4 pF + 4 pF = 8 pF.

Answer (score 4):

You effectively have two capacitors in parallel, so it is correct to add their capacitances; however, only one of those two effective capacitors is filled with the dielectric.  The dielectric-filled part you correctly note has a capacitance of 4 pF.  The other half is vacuum filled and possesses half the area of the original capacitor, so it has a capacitance of 2 pF.  Add those together, and you get the 6 pf.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, that really helped